# Remove NTFS permissions of a user in all subdirectories

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ntfs

I am writing a script which would delete a specific user if the account is older than 7 days.
But when the user is deleted the NTFS permissions on my file server remain.
How can I delete all the permission for a specific user with PowerShell?

Comment: Care to explain why you downvote my question?

Comment: I would suspect that whoever downvoted your question did so because it doesn't show any effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Hi, there is no code in your question, what have you tried?

Comment: I know how to remove permissions but i have no idea how to remove them from subfolders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should *never* grant permissions to individual users (with the exception of home directories and user profiles). As you can see for yourself it's a mess to clean up. *Always* create groups representing the particular functions/roles that require access, and grant permissions to those groups.

You can clean up the permissions via [`icacls`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx):

```
icacls C:\root\folder /remove DOMAIN\user /t /c
```

Note, however, that you MUST do this *before* deleting the account, because for some reason `icacls` can't clean up SIDs of deleted accounts.

If you have already deleted the account you can try to fix permissions with `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl`:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\root\folder -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object {
  $acl = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $_.FullName
  $ace = $acl.Access | Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -like 'S-1-5-*' }
  $acl.RemoveAccessRule($ace) | Out-Null
  Set-Acl -LiteralPath $_.FullName -AclObject $acl
}
```

Note that you may need to adjust the condition for selecting the ACE to remove from the file or folder's ACL.

Note also, that the above will fail for files/folders where the owner isn't either the user running the code or one of his groups. In a situation like that you can use tools like [`subinacl`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510) or [`SetACL`](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/) as a last resort, as described in the answers to [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/165531/134295) on ServerFault.