# Removing permissions from subfolders powershell

Tags: powershell

I wrote a simple script to delete some permissions from a specific folder

```
# remove inheritance
$acl = Get-Acl $folderPath
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)
Set-Acl $folderPath $acl

# remove an access
$acl = Get-Acl $folderPath
$acl.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]'BUILTIN\Users')
Set-Acl $folderPath $acl
```

Is there a way to delete this account from all child subfolders? I expect to have some flag or special method to do that.

As a last resort: I think to get all subfolders with Get-ChildItems cmdlet, sort them in a way that parents come always first. Sorting allows us to delete permission without removing inheritance from subfolders. Then iterate one by one removing specified permission. This approach seems to work, but it looks like inventing a weel, I believe there is must be a simpler way because the task is very common

Comment: You may have to just use gci, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41441961/14903754

Comment: If you want to have the new permissions trickle down to the subfolders, then don't remove inheritance/propagation first I would guess..